# Migrating one or multiple SQLite database files into one new db file using JDBC

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

What would be the procedure in order to migrate multiple big SQLite databases, all with the same schema that have thousands of entries, into one new database file with JDBC?

I don't have much experience in this matter and I find it difficult to find anything related to SQLite with Java on Google Search besides [this site](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/).

Comment: Can't you just use SQLite3 shell to do this?  BTW, combining multiple same schema databases into one requires knowing how to handle data collisions.  For example, same keys with different remaining columns, which one makes it to the final table?  If that's not a possibility, it's a piece of cake.

Comment: The databases have the exact same columns, one db is the main one with a certian number of records and a second db just has newer records with the same columns. Both need to go into one db. I could with the shell but was tasked to do it with java.